# Unable to change Header information like Host in Java

Tags: java, header, host

I want to change the header in java.
I need to change the host name.
But getting default host.

My code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO code application logic here
    URL oracle = new URL("http://localhost/header_received/");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
    yc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Hello World");
    yc.setRequestProperty ("Host", "entuser");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
```

Out put :

```
<br/>Authorization: Hello World
<br/>User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_21
<br/>Host: **localhost**
<br/>Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
<br/>Connection: keep-alive
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Why not connect to `http://desiredhostname/` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

try to cast your connection in HttpsURLConnection.
Here an exemple working for you :

(https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/guides/infinitydevguide/Subsystems/inwebapi-developer-help/Content/Reference/Java/rfcosaHttpURLConnectionTechniqueA.htm)

HttpsURLConnection yc = (HttpsURLConnection)oracle.openConnection();

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
 at httprequesthost.HttpRequestHost.main(HttpRequestHost.java:24)